# Get string from bundle android returns null

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

I want to pass a string from one activity to another, in one of them I wrote

public void pdfView(File f) {

```
 // f is: /data/data/com.example.iktabClasses/files/fileName.pdf

 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewPdfActivity.class);

 intent.putExtra("filename", f);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

and in the other Activity I wrote:

```
  Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();

        if (b != null) {

        filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("filename");

       System.out.println("filename: "+filename);
    }
```

but filename always returns as 'null'.
How to solve this? 
Thanks in advance.
//////////////////

I made it as

```
   Intent intent;
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putString("filename", f.toString());

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewPdfActivity.class);

    intent.putExtras(b);

    startActivity(intent);
```

and Now it work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, second.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("index", index);

intent.putExtras(bundle);startActivity(intent);
```

then get it as

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int index = b.getInt("index");
```

Answer (score 1):

in your other activity, instead of using

```
filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("filename");
```

try using

```
filename = b.getString("filename");
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in `pdfView()`, it is written as `intent.putExtra("filename", f);`.

Try to convert it to `toString()` (i.e., `intent.putExtra("filename", f.toString());`

And probably, you can skip sending the `Bundle` to explicit intent.