# Passing data with intents

Tags: android, android-intent

Why won't this work? Just trying to pass a editable string from one activity to another. But I cannot get it to work. Does the string passed through the intent have to be pre defined? If so, how can I pass a editable string?

```
   @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
     {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         textOut.setText(textIn.getText());

            Intent intent = new  Intent(TutorialOne.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("text", textIn.getText());
        startActivity(intent);
     }


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
  {

TextView gettext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gettext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.getExtras().getString("text");
    String s = intent.getStringExtra("text");
    gettext.setText(s);
    gettext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

}
```

Comment: get input like this textIn.getText().toString()

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881033/get-string-from-bundle-android-returns-null/15881224#15881224

Comment: Thank you so much, now is there a way that textin is passed with its modifiers (bold, italic, color ect?) your fix worked but I just get the plain string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Instead of this.

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
     {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textOut.setText(String.valueOf(textIn.getText()));
        Intent intent = new  Intent(TutorialOne.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("text", String.valueOf(textIn.getText()));
        startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Instead of this.

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
     {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         textOut.setText(textIn.getText());

            Intent intent = new  Intent(TutorialOne.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("text", textIn.getText());
        startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Comment: That works as well, but is there a way to keep the modifiers(italic, bold, color) of textIn, Currently the settings are changed with a switch and case with radio buttons, would i need to pass an intent for if each radio buttion ischecked? or is there a way just to pass the text + its modifications?

Comment: @EricMiller i suggest to use the sharePreference to find the type of text style like a (Italic,bold,color..etc).save the all value with pass intent.and display in next activity.

Answer (score 0):

try like this to get String

```
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String  mstr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
     {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textOut.setText(String.valueOf(textIn.getText()));
        Intent intent = new  Intent(TutorialOne.this,MainActivity.class);
        String text = textIn.getText().toString().trim();
        intent.putExtra("text", text);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Use this code