# Unfortunately app has stopped error in notification sending

Tags: android-studio, database-connection

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;
import com.htl.jsfshoppingfestival.DataBaseHandler;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    Context ctx;
    int countNotification=0;

    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("Message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification :"+message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),from+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);

        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {

        DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
        db.addMessage(message);
        countNotification=db.getRowCount();
        db.close();

        Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("badge count");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        localIntent.putExtra("Count", countNotification);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
}
}
```

I did not get the message as a notification when I send the notification, my app shows:

> Unfortunately app has stopped

In debugging I got `message=null` and app gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which block you got null? OnMessageReceived or SendNotification?

Comment: OnMessageReceived

Comment: Then surely nothing getting in `Bundle` , please check onec there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881033/get-string-from-bundle-android-returns-null this link may help you

Comment: in debug i get:-> Bundle[{subtitle=, google.sent_time=1475053305940, msgcnt=1, title=new, vibrate=1, google.message_id=0:1475053305948338%64ae29a2f9fd7ecd, message=new offers, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, tickerText=}]

Comment: @SiddharthSahni can you please format properly `Bundle` data and post.

Comment: Instead of `Bundle` send data in `Intent` ::::: `@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
    }` can you please post how you are sending data? using `Intent` or `Bundle`

Comment: thnku@ChandrakantAudhutwar.....problem solve a big thnku for your help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need check the message not equal to null.

```
if(message != null && !message.trim().isEmpty())
{
     sendNotification(message);
}
```